# How can I style active Link in react-router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In react-router v3 we had activeStyle and activeClassName to style active Link

we could do something like this

```
  <div id="tags-container">
    {tags.map(t =>
      <Link
        className="tags"
        activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
        to={t.path}
      >
        {t.title}
      </Link>
    )}
  </div>
```

I wanna know how can I do same thing in v4?

Comment: r u getting any error or not working, when using the same thing in v4,??because i think these will work with v4 in the same way.

Comment: @Mayank Shukla: Warning: Unknown prop `activeStyle` on <a> tag

Answer (score 44):

Use NavLink instead Link. Its not documented, but its work as you expect.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4318

UPDATE 17.05.2017:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Comment: Documentation is now here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/#navlink

Comment: If you are using React Router, you have to use this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Answer (score 29):

You can do it with `NavLink` in `react-router` v4

```
 <div id="tags-container">
   {tags.map(t =>
     <NavLink
       className="tags"
       activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
       to={t.path}
     >
       {t.title}
     </NavLink>
   )}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 11):

> If you are encountering an issue where **your Nav menu works except it's not updating properly** when you click links and the route changes, but it works fine if you press F5, you can do this:

This is probably occurring because you are using Redux which has a `shouldComponentUpdate` Lifecycle method on its `connect` function. You probably have your Nav component wrapped in `connect`. This is all good. `shouldComponentUpdate` is what is ruining your life.

To fix, just bring the router into your `mapStateToProps` function:

```
// This lets shouldComponentUpdate know that the route changed,
// which allows the Nav to re-render properly when the route changes, woot!
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    router: state.router,
  }
}

// or, if you prefer pro style destructure shorthand:
const mapStateToProps = ({ router }) => ({ router })
```

If you aren't quite sure where `state.router` comes from, it comes from the file you combine your reducers in, and you will see something like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import authReducer from './components/auth/auth_reducer'

export default combineReducers({
  router: routerReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
})
```

Here is some HTML and CSS for a pretty baller Nav Link:

> HTML

```
<ul id="Nav_menu">
  <li>
    <NavLink
      to="/home"
      className="Nav_link"
      activeClassName="activeRoute"
      activeStyle={{ color: 'teal' }}
    >
      HOME
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink
    to="/products"
    className="Nav_link"
    activeClassName="activeRoute"
    activeStyle={{ color: 'teal' }}
    >
      PRODUCTS
    </NavLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE:** If you are linking to `"/"`, put `exact` prop on NavLink.

> CSS

```
#Nav_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Nav_link:link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.Nav_link:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
.Nav_link:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.Nav_link:active {
  color: teal;
}

.activeRoute {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 0.4rem solid teal;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Notice `activeStyle` in the HTML markup. This was the only way I could change the color of the text on the active route/link. It didn't work when I put `color: teal;` in the `activeRoute` CSS Class. Open this in another tab: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

If you don't know why I used `rem` instead of `px`. This is a great opportunity for you to research web accessibility and base `font-size: 10px;`.

Stay fit and have fun.

Comment: `If you are linking to "/", put exact prop on NavLink.` That was useful! THX

Answer (score 4):

**React Router v6:**

Source: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router)

I know this was a question for **v4** but since **v6** is released we can accomplish this now by using `className` property which now accepts a function and passes an `isActive` boolean property, like this:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

You can also add multiple classes too, since **v6** is out:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? 'bg-green-500 font-bold' : 'bg-red-500 font-thin'
  }
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

Demo: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router)

Answer (score 3):

All still works the same. However, react-router-dom v4 replace `Link` with `NavLink`

`import { NavLink as Link } from 'react-router-dom';` is also fine. Note: Navlinks by default is active so you can style `a:active` or `activeStyle={{color: 'red'}}`

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [@agm1984's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49245229/7311767):
The solution of NavLinks is not updating styles correctly, which was using `routerReducer` from `react-router-redux`, has not worked for me. Instead, I found out that the issue was that `connect` wrapper uses `shouldComponentUpdate` and prevented rerendering of the component containing NavLinks.

Correct solution in my situation was to pass options object to `connect` as 4th parameter as shown below:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false })(NavItems);
```

Answer (score 2):

This example from the react-router v4 [custom link documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/custom-link) will help you to accomplish it:

```js
const OldSchoolMenuLink = ({ label, to, activeOnlyWhenExact }) => (
  <Route path={to} exact={activeOnlyWhenExact} children={({ match }) => (
    <div className={match ? 'active' : ''}>
      {match ? '> ' : ''}<Link to={to}>{label}</Link>
    </div>
  )}/>
);
```

So in your case you could create following component:

```js
const CustomLink = ({ activeStyle, children, className, to, activeOnlyWhenExact }) => (
  <Route path={to} exact={activeOnlyWhenExact} children={({ match }) => (
    <Link to={to} className={className} style={match && activeStyle}>{children}</Link>
  )}/>
);
```

And then use it like:

```js
  <div id="tags-container">
    {tags.map(t =>
      <CustomLink
        className="tags"
        activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
        to={t.path}
      >
        {t.title}
      </CustomLink>
    )}
  </div>
```